# When receiving a Diameter protocol message is it expected that a response will be generated and sent back to the sender?

Tags: diameter-protocol

I am currently testing a Diameter protocol receiving component using Seagull to send my Diameter messages.

I have realised I am having to manually kill the Seagull process as it is expecting a response back when the Diameter message has been received by the system under test and this is not something the system is set up to do.

before I look to change the way I send my messages to work around this issue I wanted to check if the standard process for Diameter protocol is to send a response on receipt of a message and therefore is this a requirement that has been missed during design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not familiar with a Diameter interface that includes Request without answer and I doubt if such exist since the protocol includes a lot of parameters that support request/answer mechanism (r-bit, hop-by-hop,end-to-end, Session-Id AVP....) how ever there are dozens of interfaces of Diameter so please share the interface you work with (For example: Ro,Gy,Gx,S6a...)

Regarding your Seagull case:

1. Seagull can only send and does not have to receive. Check where you have "receive channel" in your scenario XML. This where Seagull waits for answer. Remove it and you have a Seagull that only sends.
2. Every correct Diameter negotiation starts with request (CER) and Answer (CEA). If you want to simulate a full correct flow your Seagull will have to wait for answers

Comment: Great thanks, that worked perfectly :) My automated tests now run :).